# best way to mock a global static method

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

my application has a logger library with the signature:

```
final class Logger {
  public static method debug($msg);
  public static method warn($msg);
  public static method error($msg);
}
```

the class i want to test, another global static helper, use it as

```
final class TestMe {
  public static method TestThis(){
    Logger::debug('TestThis() called');
    doThings();
  }
}
```

How to test the `TestMe` class by mocking the `Logger` one and waiting for the expected messages?

Comment: If you can rewrite, or at least for future development, testability is obtained by using static instances of NON-static classes. You should be able to inject the Logger, and this logger should not have static methods so it can be mocked. As a last resort try https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Logger class cannot be mocked by PHPUnit for a couple of reasons.

1. The class is listed as `final` which means that it cannot be extended.  When PHPUnit creates a mock of an object, it creates a new object that extends the class being mocked.  The `final` keyword prevents extending a class, so a mock cannot be created.
2. The methods that you want to replace are being called statically. You are not able to replace them because the calls are being directed to the actual class.  [PHPUnit 5.3 has a way of "mocking" static methods but that is only within the class being called statically.](https://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html)  It doesn't replace calls from outside of the class.

http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

You have two options for testing things like this:

1. Increase the scope of the behavior that you are testing.  Assert that whatever the `Logger` class is doing gets done.  This will make any tests less of a "unit" test but they do encapsulate the behavior that is expected and can still be useful.
2. Refactor your usages to use dependency injection, so that you can pass in a `mockLogger` that doesn't call the methods statically.  This may be more painful but will result in your code more flexible IMO.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a testing framework like PHPUnit, it offers the ability to mock an object. You could create a mock object for your logger class and define the debug method in it.

It is explained in details here :

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Here is a little example taken from that page :

```
<?php
require_once 'SomeClass.php';

class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
                     ->getMock();

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('doSomething')
             ->willReturn('foo');

        // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
        // 'foo'.
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: when i call `->method()` on the mock builder for the static class it fails saying there is no such method.

Comment: just noticed this on the manual: `Limitations

Please note that final, private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked.`

Comment: This does not work for static method like the question wants.